# Will user validate if AD password expired?

Tags: .net, iis-7, active-directory, ldap

Can user be validated with valid username and password if his/her password is expired? (suppose AD password policy is 90 days expiration)

Basically, What is the behaviour of Membership.ValidateUser method if user's password is expired?

And will it work on both local IIS as well as hosted server IIS?

VSTS2010, ASP.NET 4.0 , C# 4.0, IIS7, Winodws 7, windows Sever 008 R2

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, a user that has an expired password cannot successfully bind to an AD over LDAP:

```
[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C8, comment: 
AcceptSecurityContext error, data 773, v2580]
```

The purpose of `Membership.ValidateUser` is to check if a user is able to authenticate to the server, which in the above case is not possible.

Comment: Hello @mvreijn I know, I was assuming the same if password is expired the validate user method should return false. But it is not happening, but thank for sharing this information. And I am using Windows 2008 R2 servers

Comment: Funny - my server was the same revision, W2008 R2.